# Using sigalarm logic in Windows

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I am making file conversation between two formats. If it takes too long, I want to skip that file and continue. Here is the script that I am using:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from os.path import basename
import os, glob

# Custom exception class
class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass


# Custom alarm handler
class Alarm(Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.timeout)
        raise TimeoutException
for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
     if any([filename.endswith('.scad') for filename in filenames]):
         if filename.endswith('.scad'):
             os.chdir(folder)
             of = filename.replace('.scad', '.stl') # name of the outfile .stl
             # This try/except loop ensures that
             #   you'll catch TimeoutException when it's sent.
             try:
                 alarm = Alarm(5) # Create the timer. Once 5 seconds are over, a alarm will go off.
                 alarm.start() # Start the timer
                 os.system("\"convert.exe\" -o {} {}".format(of, filename))
             except TimeOutException:
                 print("Timed out for file name: {}".format("filename"))
             else:
                 del alarm # Reset the alarm
```

How could I make the script work in Windows? I referred sigalarm in Linux, but couldn't make it work in windows

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal):  `On Windows, signal() can only be called with SIGABRT, SIGFPE, SIGILL, SIGINT, SIGSEGV, or SIGTERM. A ValueError will be raised in any other case.`

Comment: You'll have to come up with a multithreaded/processing approach.

Comment: Well actually I tried by using concurrent futures and asyncio.coroutine but it didn't work